# Spring MVC doesn't keep values from object in View

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

First i open my site, this will call the following method from my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView list() {
    return new ModelAndView("view/overview").addObject("connection", new Connection()).addObject("customMethod", new CustomMethod());
}
```

Now i fill in some information from gui and save them in the connection object:

```
@PostMapping("/connectiontest")
public ModelAndView conntectionTest(DBConnection connection) {
    system.out.println(connection.info);            
    return new ModelAndView("view/overview").addObject("connection", connection);
}
```

In my console there is the value i entered in the gui, so all is fine.
And you see i send the filled object back to the view.

Now i called a other method where i need the filled connection object and a second object.

```
@PostMapping("/execute")
public ModelAndView execute(@ModelAttribute("connection") DBConnection connection, CustomMethod method) {
    method.execute(connection);

    return new ModelAndView("view/overview").addObject("connection", connection).addObject("customMethod", method);
}
```

But in the connection object is no value i entered before.
How can i pass the connection object with my values to the last method?

Comment: how do you inject CustomMethod in execute?

Comment: By the looks of it, even if you manage to get it working, this will not be thread-safe at all... Most likely you will run in several concurrency problems if you run with multiple users or even multiple tabs on your browser.

Comment: The object is, by design, reconstructed on every request. So either you have to send all the data back and forth or use `@SessionAttributes` to store it in between requests for the same controller.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. But what is the default solution to handle this? Is it  to store the objects in a session, or how i should do it?